# Returning different enum in overriden method

Tags: c++, enums, overriding, c++03

Suppose that you have to design in C++03 a system where you have to manage different type of messages coming from different sources.

All messages have in common a property that is the ID, a number that represents the *meaning* of data contained by the message.

So the ID is related to the source, and different sources can have in common ID of other sources. That is *SourceA* and *SourceB* can send a message with ID set to 1, despite the meaning of the data inside the message is completely different.

So a base class representing a message could be declared as following:

```
enum SourceType {
    SourceA,
    SourceB,
    // ...
};

struct Message {
    virtual int getID();
    virtual SourceType getSource();
    // ...
};
```

Since I would like to avoid to spread *magic number* around my code I would like to replace the `int` with some more meaningful `enum`, but since each source have their own different enumeration is not possible.

One solution could be casting the `int` to the proper `enum` using the information returned by `getSource`, but it seems a very flawless design.

Another solution could be to define a big enum with all the possible ID for all the sources having a lot of value duplication (that is not an error), like the following:

```
enum MessageID {
    SourceA_ID1,
    SourceA_ID2,
    SourceB_ID1,
    SourceB_ID2,
    // ...
};
```

And so the `getID` message could return `MessageID`, but this mean that MessageID will explode in size and could be a little messy to be maintained and documented.

Comment: So the parsing dispatcher uses `SourceType` and message ID to instantiate the correct payload types? I'm not sure I understood your design fully. Such kind of deferred parsing using message IDs is already implemented by systems like google protocol buffers BTW.

Comment: Basically the idea is to have a system able to manage different messages coming from different sources, each source *talk* a different language, so the parsing depend on the couple (source, message ID). I cannot use third party libraries since I am using an old embedded system (PowerPC) with severe restrictions.

Comment: Why not return a `pair` (or a `tuple` if available)? One component is the numeric ID of the source and the other is the numeric ID of the message. That way, software that receives the pair only has to know how to match the first component to their own ID value and cast to the corresponding `enum` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with your first alternative:

> One solution could be casting the int to the proper enum using the
>   information returned by getSource, but it seems a very flawless
>   design.

Basically `enum` is equals to `int`. It exists as an easy way to create constants and avoid magic numbers across the code. So it's possible to have:

```
enum SourceType {
    SourceA,
    SourceB,
    // ...
};

struct Message {
    virtual int getID();
    virtual SourceType getSource();
    // ...
};

// Maybe in "sourceA.h"
enum SourceA_Ids {
    SourceA_ID1 = 1, 
    SourceA_ID2 = 12, 
    SourceA_ID3 = 20
};

// Maybe in "sourceB.h"
enum SourceB_Ids {
    SourceB_ID1 = 1, 
    SourceB_ID2 = 2, 
    SourceB_ID3 = 3
};
```

And in your code, make the assignments and comparisons directly without need to cast anything, because enum to int is implicit:

```
// sourceA.h
struct MessageFromSourceA: Message {
    double data;
    ...
    MessageFromSourceA() {
        source = SourceA;
        data = 0;
    }
};

// sourceA.cpp
void processMsgFromSourceA(Message &msg) {
    if (msg.getID() == SourceA_ID1) {
        // Send an answer
        MessageFromSourceA msga;
        msga.id = SourceA_ID2;
        msga.data = 123.456;
        send(msga);
    }
}
```

As you see: no magical numbers, no compiling errors.